Ruby on Rails: how to efficiently save nested attributes (recursively)?
I'm using Rails 6.1.3.2 and trying to make saving of nested attributes more efficient. The database used is MySQL.
Code basis
BoardSet.rb
class BoardSet < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :boards, inverse_of: :board_set, foreign_key: 'board_set_id', dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards

Board.rb
class Board < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cells, inverse_of: :board, foreign_key: 'board_id', dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :cells

Cell.rb
class Cell < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :board, inverse_of: :cells, foreign_key: 'board_id'

There is Grape::API endpoint like this:
params do
  requires :name, type: String, desc: 'BoardSet name'
  optional :boards, as: :boards_attributes, type: Array[JSON] do
    # more params
    optional :cells, as: :cells_attributes, type: Array[JSON] do
      # more params
    end
  end
end
post do
  board_set = BoardSet.new(declared(params, include_missing: false))
  board_set.save!
end

Functionality
Summary of code basis: a BoardSet contains Boards which contain Cells. There is a Grape::API endpoint, where data can be passed to via PUT, which is then saved within the database.
Problem
Saving with board_set.save! is very inefficient. A BoardSet typically contains 40 Boards, where each contain maybe 20 Cells. So in total there are more than 40 * 20 = 800 SQL INSERT statements (a single one for each Cell).
Solution attempts
I've tried these attempts for improvements:

use the gem activerecord-import which seems to be able to do bulk inserts for such situations. However I think I would need something like BoardSet.import [board_set], recursive: true, but recursive is only supported for PostgeSQL, so not for MySQL, which I'm using.
first save board_set including boards with empty cells, then transferring the ID of the boards to the cells and save them in bulk. However I didn't manage to remove the cells, I've tried to use cloned_board = board.dup and cloned_board.cells = [] for saving empty copies, but it still saves all cells at cloned_board_set.save! (where cloned_board_set contains cloned boards with emtpy cells).
I've tried to remove accepts_nested_attributes_for :cells from Board.rb in order to prevent board_set.save! from automatically saving all the cells. However this results in an exception in BoardSet.new(declared(params, include_missing: false)) since the parameter cells_attributes it not known.


You might have to implement yourself by separating the parameters internally but the functionality I believe you are looking for is provided by ActiveRecord::Persistence::ClassMethods#upsert_all. This page suggests you can overwrite the autosave_associated_record_for_XXX method to implement this functionality, although I have not tested it so I cannot confirm.

Do you need to represent the board as 20 records in a cells table? Could it be a simple array column on the boards table?

@engineersmnky - thanks I've also already found that page suggesting overwriting autosave_associated_record_for_XXX, but since it's not documented I thought there must be a better way.
@user229044 yes, that's what I'm also wondering. I'm not an expert in architectures for relational databases. I've read that many rows in a table are fine, but I've also thought that saving cells directly within the boards maybe would be the best solution?!

Instead of saving all the objects with one line try these 3 steps:

Save the board set with only its name i.e. without nested attributes.
Save all boards without nested attributes
Save all cells

After rails 6 we can do insert all
board_set = BoardSet.new(declared(params[:name], include_missing: false))

Thanks, that's exactly what I've tried. However I didn't manage to save the boards without the nested cells. I've tried to duplicate them with board.dup and then removing the cells with duplicated_board.cells = [], but saving it with duplicated_board.save still saves all the cells. I have no clue why.

try after removing accepts_nested_attributes_for

ok, finally I found out why cells were always created, also if I removed them from the parameters. The class Board had some hook after_create :populate_cells where cells were auto-created according to the dimensions of the board, if not existing. What makes sense when creating empty boards, doesn't if I want to create the boards first and then all the cells in a single bulk operation. Finally I've created a class BoardNoAutocells < Board with no after_create hook and then followed your answer. Seems not to be the cleanest solution, but at least a solution.
